# How to show equivalence of definitions ot the Rieman tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

The Riemann tensor can be thought of as a map from a triple of vectors X, Y ,
Z to a fourth vector, written in a coordinate-free way as

$R(X, Y )Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z − \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z − \nabla_{[X,Y ]}Z\tag 1$

where the notation $\nabla X = X^\mu\nabla_{\mu}$ refers to the covariant derivative along the vector X, so that (1) is equivalent to

$R^ρ_{σμν} X^μY^νZ^σ = X^λ∇_λ(Y^η∇_ηZ^ρ) − Y^λ∇_λ(X^η∇_ηZ^ρ) −(X^λ∂_λY^η − Y^λ∂_λX^η)∇_ηZ^ρ \tag 2$

How do I show that this is equivalent to the usual definition of the Riemann tensor in terms of Christoffel symbols?

That is, to:

$R^a_{bcd}X^cY^dZ^d=X^c\partial_c(\Gamma^a_{db})Y^dZ^b-Y^d\partial_d(\Gamma^a_{cb})Y^cZ^b+ \Gamma^a_{cm}\Gamma^m_{db}X^cY^dZ^b-\Gamma^a_{dm}\Gamma^m_{cd}X^cY^dZ^b \tag 3$

I 've trying for a while but I getting lost with indices

Comment: plug in $X,Y,Z$ to be coordinate vector fields. What do you get when you do this?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Could you should as an example how to deal with at least one of the terms in (2) when you do that? I am having a hard time

Comment: Ok, so (3) looks roughly right, $\partial\Gamma-\partial\Gamma+\Gamma\Gamma-\Gamma\Gamma$ with suitable indices. To really be sure, like I said, you should plug in coordinate vector fields for $X,Y,Z$, i.e $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^c}$ (so $X^c=1$ and $X^i=0$ for $i\neq c$), and likewise with $Y,Z$. Then, many of the terms are either $0$ or $1$, so you should be able to simplify the terms nicely.

Comment: Try Do Carmo Riemannian Geometry, in his book this is explained quite well.

Comment: I suggest that you keep trying but writing really neatly and slowly and keeping close track of the indices. Rename an index when the same letter is being used for two different indices. I also find it useful to do this kind of calculation on a large blackboard.